# How to use a segmented control to define integers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, c-preprocessor

I have three numbers that I have defined:

```
#define kBallSpeedX = 4;
#define kBallSpeedY = 3;
#define kCpuSpeed = 3.25;
```

But I want these numbers to change when the other part of a segmented controller is selected. How do I do this?

Comment: Show us what you've written so far so we can point out where you've gone wrong.

Comment: You want the values to vary.. use a variable. Those are (ill formatted) constants.

Comment: @burkel: it looks like Paul's answer below solved your problem - please accept it by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you don't define macros like this - it should be:

```
#define kBallSpeedX 4
#define kBallSpeedY 3
#define kCpuSpeed 3.25
```

Secondly, you shouldn't really be using macros - use actual variables (and make them const if appropriate), e.g.

```
double kBallSpeedX = 4.0;
double kBallSpeedY = 3.0;
const double kCpuSpeed = 3.25;
```

You can then modify kBallSpeedX, kBallSpeedY as appropriate.

Comment: Cool thx. That was exactly what I was looking for!! And I actually had the top one in my code but I wrote it wrong here :P thx

Comment: A tip for future reference: never re-type code for SO questions (or anything else) - always use copy and paste so that you are posting the code *verbatim*, not an approximation of it.